# Disable Windows screensaver (media players can do it)

Tags: windows

Windows 7, Domain policies enforce a password protected screensaver with a timeout of 10 minutes. I'm trying to find a way to prevent the screensaver from kicking in.

I've noticed that when I play a video (even when minimised) the screensaver is not activated.

What is the mechanism that allows a video player to disable the screensaver, even though I'm running as a normal (non-admin) user?

Can I simulate this behaviour in a way that is less cpu-intensive? Maybe periodicaly writing a registry setting? Or perhaps 'writing' something to the video card?

Comment: I believe applications can use the SetThreadExecutionState() API call to advise Windows that they need the display to remain visible.  Fairly straightforward to implement unless your domain policies use application whitelisting.  Be aware that (depending on your situation) deliberately bypassing domain policy may be a firing offence.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [Power Request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options#option_requestsoverride) type Display.

There is also an [explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/1181186/power-request-types-whats-the-difference-between-display-system-awaymode-p) here.

Just try `powercfg /requestsoverride process explorer.exe display`.

Comment: This command seems to require administrator privileges.